# How to capture who ran the pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How to capture who ran the build pipeline in Azure DevOps as a variable?

Is there any predefined variable to capture that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its called: "Build.QueuedBy"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables):

`Build.QueuedBy` - See "[How are the identity variables set?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#identity_values)".

Note: This value can contain whitespace or other invalid label characters. In these cases, the label format will fail.

`Build.QueuedById` - See "[How are the identity variables set?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#identity_values)".